# proof $\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}^n}$ converges to 0

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Proof the sequence $a_n=\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}^n}$ converges to 0.

My attempt was to show using induction that, for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$,

$$\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}^n}<\frac{5}{n},$$

But I can't proof it even though it's true.

Comment: You could take the ratio between $a_{n+1},a_n$ is smaller than $1$ hence the sequence converges to 0 ($a_n>0$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $$\sqrt[n]{\frac{n}{(\sqrt{2})^n}}=\frac{\sqrt[n]{n}}{\sqrt{2}}\to\frac{1}{2}<1,$$ the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(\sqrt{2})^n}$$ converges. That is why our sequence tends to zero.

Comment: can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I have applied Cauchy Test (Root Test) of convergence of series.

Comment: @ szw1710 OP may be confused because question is about sequence and you start with series. (I know your argument is correct - just want to point this out in case OP does not know about series.)

Comment: @szw1710 Figuring out what $\frac{\sqrt[n]{n}}{\sqrt 2}$ converges to is not actually any easier easier than the original problem. So it's a bit silly to use it as one step of the argument.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, please leave the comments what is silly or not, for yourself.

Comment: @szw1710 If you prefer me to be more specific, I think that it is not a complete answer unless you also prove that the limit of $\frac{\sqrt[n]{n}}{\sqrt 2}$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Now I understand what you wanted to tell me. OK. You are right. It is not so easy to prove it. I know a nice proof with the use of AM-GM ineguality. Namely, take $$1\le \sqrt[n]{n}=\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{n}\cdot\sqrt{n}\cdot 1\cdots 1}\le \frac{2\sqrt{n}+n-2}{n}\to 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n = \frac n{\sqrt2^n}$. Then
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} = \frac{(n+1)/\sqrt{2}^{n+1}}{n/\sqrt2^{n}} = \frac{n+1}{\sqrt2n}
$$
which quickly becomes smaller than $1$.